# How to combine a control command with a parameterized query in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

According to this [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/#combining-queries-and-control-commands) the result of a control command can be used in a query by using `$command_results`.

Now, how to achieve that when the query makes use of query_parameters?

```
.show tables;
declare query_parameters(_rootPath:string = "root")
$command_results
| where Folder startswith _rootPath
```

This throws

```
400 - "General_BadRequest: Request is invalid and cannot be executed.
Syntax error: Query could not be parsed: SYN0002: A recognition error occurred. [line:position=3:0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing a semicolon (`;`) after `declare query_parameters(_rootPath:string = "root")`